# Laptop shuts down and reboot when loading system

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, shutdown, acer-aspire

I received an Acer laptop of a friend and I try to fix it, but I'm out of inspiration.

When the laptop boots and loads its OS (Windows 7) the laptop shuts down and reboots automatically, but doing the same (creates an infinte loop).
When I put a livecd from Linux or a windows 7 install cd, it also shutdowns when it's loading the setup or environment.
I tried to replace the hard drive, but this didn't do also a change.

The only thing that works is installing Windows 7 in safe mode, but after the first reboot of the installation Windows 7 rejects to continue the installation in safe mode. When I proceed the installation in normal mode, the pc shuts down again...

For me, this looks like a virus in the boot sector. My question is, what can I do about this in this situation?

Comment: Boot into safe mode, within Safe Mode, configure a minimal driver configuration.  Continue to use modify this configuration until you find the problem driver.

Comment: I don't have an OS on the HDD anymore, so I can't boot in safe mode anymore.

Comment: You didn't mention that fact iny our question.  If you don't have a HDD, you should purchase a HDD, and install it in the system.  If you don't have operating sytem, you should install an operating system, and boot to it.

Comment: "this looks like a virus in the boot sector." - If you no longer have the HDD then it isn't a virus.